# find a subset of predictions which maximize the number of correct majority decision

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

Assuming I have a multi-class sequence prediction problem, with the correct answer:

```
gold = [1,2,1,0,2,2]
```

There are N models which gives different predictions:

```
pred1 = [1,2,2,0,2,2]
pred2 = [2,2,1,1,1,1]
pred3 = [1,2,1,0,2,1]
pred4 = [1,1,0,2,1,2]
pred5 = [2,2,1,0,1,2]
```

I would like to find a subset of the predictions (e.g. [pred1, pred3, pred5]), such that if I take the most common item at each position, the number of correct voting results is maximized.

In the actually problem, the length of sequence > 10000, and N > 100, is there any efficient way to find the subset?

Currently I am simply randomly sampling the subset, since I couldn't find an exact search algorithm (nor do I know if it exists). Some heuristics could help to reduce the computation, e.g. remove the unanimous predictions, but not complexity-wise.

If an efficient answer doesn't exist, I would also like to have a solution on a relaxed problem: namely binary instead of multi-class prediction, such that the most common prediction is the majority (>50%) one.

(Solutions with Python/Numpy native functions are appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be similar to the ["set cover problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is NP-complete. It means that you won't find a perfect, fast solution.

The first step could be to sort the lists according to how close they are from the goal:

```
gold = [1,2,1,0,2,2]

preds = [
    [1,2,2,0,2,2],
    [2,2,1,1,1,1],
    [1,2,1,0,2,1],
    [1,1,0,2,1,2],
    [2,2,1,0,1,2]
]

def count_correct(pred, goal=gold):
    return sum(1 for a,b in zip(pred, goal) if a==b)

print(sorted(preds, key=count_correct, reverse=True))
# [[1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]]
```

You could also calculate the indices for which the predictions are correct, and try to look for a set cover:

```
def correct_ids(pred, goal=gold):
    return [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(pred,goal)) if a==b]
print([correct_ids(pred) for pred in preds])
# [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5]]
```

Note that your problem is slightly different though, because the non-correct elements play a role in the voting process.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your suggest, i am using genetic algorithm to do heuristic search now.